# What to set as the Provider's value in order to change context from a Consumer, in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to learn how to use hooks and context in React, but need to work with TypeScript (new to that as well).

My use case is authorization: A user is either logged in or not, and has a role (e.g. 'Admin', 'Super Admin'). Depending on their authorization status, a navbar is rendered differently.

Among others, I'm trying to follow along to [this](https://mitchellsimoens.com/2019/08/01/react-state-provider-hook/) example, simplified to my needs.

Here's my context and provider so far:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, Context, FC SetStateAction, useState } from 'react';

export interface IAuth {
    loggedIn: boolean,
    role: string
}

export const AuthContext = React.createContext<IAuth>({
    loggedIn: false,
    role: ''
});

const AuthProvider: FC = ({children}) => {

    const [auth, setAuth] = useState({
        loggedIn: false,
        role: ''
    });

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={/*What to set as value?*/}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )

}

export default AuthProvider;
```

Then there's my NavBar, which used the context's Consumer:

```
class Nav extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (

            <AuthContext.Consumer>
                {context => (
                    < div >
                       .. stuff ...
                        </div>
                        <ul className="nav">
                            {context.loggedIn ? (
                                <Fragment> .. links .. </Fragment>
                            ) : (<Fragment> .. links .. </Fragment>
                            )}
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                )
                }
            </AuthContext.Consumer>

        )
    }
} export default Nav;
```

All this works fine if I set the Provider's value as such:

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={{
    loggedIn: false,
    role: 'someRole'
}}>
```

However, I also want to provide the `setAuth` function, in order to change these values from the Login components and such.

Using the following gives me errors:

```
<EmailContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
```

namely `Type '({ loggedIn: boolean; role: string; } | Dispatch<SetStateAction<{ loggedIn: boolean; role: string; }>>)[]' is missing the following properties from type 'IAuth': loggedIn, role`

Using the following also gives me errors:

```
   <AuthContext.Provider value={{data: auth,
                                    updateAuth: () => { setAuth({... auth, loggedIn: true})}
        }}>
```

Error on `data: auth`: `Type '{ data: { loggedIn: boolean; role: string; }; updateAuth: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IAuth'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'data' does not exist in type 'IAuth'.`

Similar errors for various other things I tried.

These are all Typescript errors. How do I set my Provider value - and include `set` actions and not just values - in a Typescript compatible way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First define an interface with everything that should be passed through the context

```
export interface IAuth {
    loggedIn: boolean;
    role: string;
    logIn: () => void;
    logOut: () => void;
}
```

Then the Provider

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext<IAuth>(null);

const AuthProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState({
        loggedIn: false,
        role: ""
    });

    const logIn = () => {
        setAuth(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            loggedIn: true
        }));
    };

    const logOut = () => {
        setAuth(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            loggedIn: false
        }));
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            // Here as value you need to pass the same interface as IAuth
            // You can also just pass setAuth and do whatever you want
            // from the children
            value={{ 
                ...auth,
                logIn,
                logOut
            }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Then in your consumer you can use [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook to access the values

```
const Child: FC = () => {
    const { loggedIn, role, logIn, logOut } = useContext(AuthContext);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{`loggedIn: ${loggedIn}`}</p>
            <p>{`role: ${role}`}</p>
            <button onClick={logIn}>logIn</button>
            <button onClick={logOut}>logOut</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

And last render the `Child` as the children of `AuthProvider`

```
const App: FC = () => (
    <AuthProvider>
        <Child />
    </AuthProvider>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the auth and setAuth state in your context this is one way to do it:

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext<IAuth>({{}, ()=> {}});
```

```
const [auth, setAuth] = useState({
        loggedIn: false,
        role: ''
    });

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{auth, setAuth}}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
```

In the nav component, you can import `{AuthContext}` and

```
const {auth, setAuth} = React.useContext(AuthContext)
```

You don't need to use renderProps with hooks. You can directly use the value of `auth` in your code.

PS: I have never used typescript, but the react way still stands the same.

Comment: I think you have a type here `{{}. ()=> {}}`